# Win api's SendMessage waits forever

Tags: java, windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2

I have a GUI application on windows 7 64 bit (service pack 1)
My GUI application has some Java in it and it dispatches Delphi code -

Lately, after upgrading to a multicore PC - we've noticed that some heavy GUI actions cause the GUI to get stuck. We only have one thread that updates our GUI.

After debugging it, we noticed that once in a while, a call made by delphi to win api's "SendMessage" just waits for ever.

We then tried to set the program's affinity to 1 - and the problem was solved, but it slows down our application.

I know that it is common to replace SendMessage with PostMessage or SendMessageTimeout, but there are many places where we use SendMessage + we also use DevExpress components that also use SendMessage - we can't possibly map all these places.

What seems most bizarre is that even though our GUI has one thread, set affinity to 1 solves the problem (there are other background threads in the system, but they are all pure java and perform some data calculations).

my questions are:

1. Any known ways to fix this problem? Maybe known bugs in Windows 7?
2. Is it possible that the messages I sent is somehow lost? Is there a limit to the total messages or rate? If so, how can I increase these limits?
3. How can I get more information - for example: check somewhere in windows what happened to my message - where/why did windows get stuck etc.
   Any way of further analyzing the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you think the bug is in Windows? Why do you not think that the fault lies in your code? Your program has a fault (sounds like deadlock) and you won't make progress until you accept that. And we cannot help very much with no code and no detailed information.

Comment: While you state that you have a single thread that updates the GUI, you didn't specifically state whether your GUI is in fact single threaded. In other words, are **all** windows in the GUI owned by the same thread? Another point you didn't explicitly address: Do your calls to `SendMessage` cross thread boundaries?

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.

I have no problem accepting that this my problem. So, accepted it. Any  tools/ways to drill down and find out what might be causing it? For example, where there might be a deadlock etc.?

Yes, my application is multithreaded - but only one thread controls the GUI. The GUI itself is written in delphi - more accuratley, we use DevExpress components and also FastMM to manage memory.

The GUI itself is also multi-threaded. But my control is single-threaded - so any interaction with other threads has to be an interaction with threads from fastMM/delphi/DevExpress.

Comment: Start by finding out what the GUI thread in question (the thread which should have processed the message) is doing while SendMessage is hung.  Ideally you would use a debugger to do this, but if that isn't possible you may just have to start logging everything the relevant thread(s) do in great detail.

Comment: When the app is hung break into it, and use the thread window to find out what the threads are doing look for one thread waiting on another thread. See if you can find the deadlock that way.

Comment: A multithreaded GUI introduces pain, no matter what, in particular if you have child/parent or owned/owner relationships across threads. Little known fact: `GetMessage`/`PeekMessage` **dispatch** in-bound nonqueued messages sent from other threads. Dispatching messages generally results in other messages being generated, an instant deadlock opportunity. To analyze your issue I would recommend using WinDbg. Using the [`!locks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563985.aspx) command will produce a list of potential deadlocked synchronization objects.

Comment: Multi-threaded UIs are also dangerous when dealing with VCL, because a control's HWND may jump from its original thread to another thread that does not know how to handle the controls messages anymore, thus killing/deadlocking that control.

Answer (score 7):

`SendMessage()` relies on the target window's message queue when sending a  message across thread boundaries.  This is documented behavior:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950.aspx

> If the specified window was created by a different thread, the system switches to that thread and calls the appropriate window procedure. Messages sent between threads are processed only when the receiving thread executes message retrieval code. The sending thread is blocked until the receiving thread processes the message.

Thus, `SendMessage()` will not exit until the target thread has retrieved the message from its message queue and then either processes the message in full or calls [`ReplyMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644948.aspx) to release `SendMessage()` while continuing to process the message.

So, if `SendMessage()` is getting stuck, it means the target thread is not processing its message queue, which is a good indication that the target thread is likely deadlocked waiting on something else.

The fact that your app runs fine when locked down to 1 CPU core but has problems when allowed to run on multiple CPU cores means your app is likely not performing inter-thread synchronizations in a multi-core safe manner.  In a single-core system, only one thread can physically run at any given moment.  Because of the way the OS uses thread scheduling and task switches to handle concurrency, unsafe syncs may be "safe enough" in some cases.  But multiple cores can truly run in parallel, so it is possible for threads running on different cores to access memory/resources at the exact same moment, so it is very important that inter-thread syncs are done correctly to make sure that is not allowed to happen, otherwise your app can get out of sync with itself, and all kinds of bad things can happen (case in point - your deadlock).

Comment: Frankly, I do not understand the upvotes. While everything you say is correct in itself, it is based on assumptions that no longer hold, since the OP replied to the comments asking for clarification. Notably, the fact that the GUI is multithreaded shifts the likely cause away from synchronization issues to cross thread message handling. (This comment is not directed towards the author, but rather the upvote-happy members of this site.)